# cannot remove pv from lvm config when disk unavailable

Tags: lvm

I have a vm with 2 disk and 2 VG, on of the disk is a PV (no partition). OS is CentOS 7.
Now the disk is unavailable. The PVS displays:

```
# pvs
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL.
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree  
  ...
  [unknown]  vgbackup lvm2 a-m  <800,00g <30,00g

--- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vgbackup
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        0
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                0
  VG Size               <800,00 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              204799
  Alloc PE / Size       197120 / 770,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       7679 / <30,00 GiB
  VG UUID               d2QWd0-eg28-RpRY-RX0h-JV7A-dpJH-jRF71x
```

The VG consist of only this disk, no other pv in this vg.
Tried to remove pv:

```
vgremove --force vgbackup 
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL.
  Aborting vg_write: No metadata areas to write to!
```

Tried to add a loop device to write metadata:

```
# losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /tmp/tmp.raw

# vgextend vgbackup /dev/loop0
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL.
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
Segmentation fault
```

The /dev/loop0 PV was created but not attached to vgbackup:

```
# pvs
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Device for PV L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid L9Anor-qlzF-mTT7-Rxx0-Ovig-hMQI-OkupZL.
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree  
  /dev/loop0          lvm2 ---   100,00m 100,00m
  /dev/sda2  rootvg   lvm2 a--    58,80g   4,00m
  [unknown]  vgbackup lvm2 a-m  <800,00g <30,00g
```

What to do now?
How can I remove vgbackup  from the lvm config?
Reboot is not an option now.

Thank you for your help!